# В C++ cin, а в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c++

Я изучаю С++, и мне стало интересно (Я НЕ ЗНАЮ JAVASCRIPT), как на JavaScript будет команда cin>>.

Comment: .............. prompt

Comment: на самом деле это поверхностно......т.к. для консоли  вроде бы ничего нет (не помню точно) ...если только это не nodejs.......... а вот в браузере можно хоть prompt хоть input использовать